# Why does overridden method in subclass calls method from superclass?

Tags: java, swing, oop

I have a class that extends `JInternalFrame`. I overridden `public void dispose()`.

It looks like this

```
@Override
public void dispose(){
   setVisible(false);
}
```

Even though I didn't call `super.dispose()`, it seems to me that overridden method `dispose()` calls it. Why is that?

Thanks!

EDIT (Additional info):

Example:
I have 5 objects of class that extends `JInternalFrame` displayed in `JDesktopPane` object.
When I click exit (that calls `dispose()`) on one window (`JInternalFrame`), the number of Components in `JDesktopPane` lowers by one.
This is the action of `super.dispose()` method. And also an overridden method `dispose()` is called, which I checked by printing on console

EDIT: 
I solved my problem by calling `this.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE)` instead of overriding `dispose()` method. But I still wonder why this happens...

Comment: What makes you think it is called?

Comment: Are you sure it does?

Comment: if you think then why not simply use a debugger and see what is happening.

Comment: @Berger check edit!

Comment: I think you're calling the super from somewhere else, bcz it should override it unless you are telling it to call the super directly.

Comment: A side note: By default, `dispose()` causes a `setVisible(false)`, so I wonder why you tried overriding it like that in the first place. Beyond that, a [MCVE] would be helpful.

Comment: @Marco13 Because `super.dispose()` deletes component from `JDesktopPane` object. Am I right?
btw thanks for the article!

Comment: It fires some events, one of them *might* be caught by the `JDesktopPane` and cause a removal (I don't know - and I don't care, because) **disposing** is *meant* be be destructive in this sense. When you dispose it and afterwards still *use* it, bad things may happen. So very broadly (even though this is not the point of your question, which might be a case of a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248000) ) : What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

Comment: Aaaah - I somehow expected that already: The default `defaultCloseOperation` is `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`. So when closing the frame, `dispose()` is called. If you don't want this, do **not** override `dispose`, but simply set the desired default close operation (as you mentioned in your last edit)

Comment: To hide JInternalFrame by clicking exit button, but I solved it by calling `this.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE) `  in constructor of class. @Marco13

Comment: @Marco13 Yep, that's my answer! Thanks :)